# API with Lyrics and Timestamps

Tags: javascript, musixmatch

I'm trying to make an app that uses lyrics with timestamps! I've looked into Genius and musiXmatch API but have had 0 success. MusiXMatch in particular requires a commercial plan to access their subtitled songs but I am making a personal app. Is there a lyrics API with timestamps that I can get access to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://textyl.co/ has lyrics with timestamps and you don't need to sign up for anything. However, it doesn't have great documentation and doesn't always get the song correctly, even with the artist and song name.
Example: https://api.textyl.co/api/lyrics?q=the%20beatles%20norwegian%20wood

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: The link is invalid please give another working link.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure about an API, but I understand that some of my friends have used this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format). Seems useful to what you are trying to do and I do think there are some websites/APIs that provide LRC files for songs.

Comment: I'll look into it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have any idea how the syncing part works?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the API I created on RapidAPI, there you can pass the name of any song and it will extract the lyrics of the song of whatever language it will be. The link to check for my API is given below

https://rapidapi.com/yashmakan261/api/timestamp-lyrics